# Add search bar on a custom built page in SharePoint 201 Foundation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, search

I am new to SharePoint 2010 but I have managed to build a few pages in SharePoint designer 2010.

I could do with having the search box feature adding to my custom built page. When I try to add search part from designer I get error 404.

Is there any way of adding the site search facility to a custom built page?

Sorry if this is something basic but I can't get my head around.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your developing a webpart page. Once created you then can go into code view in SPD and then add the search webpart within PlaceHolderMain tag.

1) create a webpart page

[image]

2) select advanced mode

[image]

3) at the bottom select split to view code and design view

[image]

4) select main placeholder where you want to add the search box

[image]

5) top menu select insert -> then select "web part" -> under search select "Search Box"

[image]

6) search box is now added to the form. so you can save

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't want all the bar etc at the top only just to show the search bar. So it can search the entire site behind that page. I would have thought there would be a way in a standard page to just insert a search facility but there does not seem to be.